# Can firebase generate an unique ID as we wish?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Like **firebase** generating **uid**. Can firebase generate an unique ID as we wish? If it is possible? how to write a code for it in the following order?

> For example    PRO00013,  PRO00014,  PRO00015....

I am asking here, because I'm working in a project for online shopping. when a user adds a product to their inventory it needs to assign an id for every product. that is must be in the human readable format. If it is not possible, just tell me no, I can accept that answer.

Comment: Can you at least tell us why

Comment: i am updated please check it. thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

You can just call .push() to get randomUUID and then ref.child(randomUUID).setValue(object)
where the object can contain field ID such as PRO00013.
If this doesn't fit your needs you can just place ref.child("PRO00013").setValue(object) and not include field id in this object.
Now you want to get id PRO00014 for the next pushed object. This ain't gonna happen with firebase.
But you can get the last ID added in this ref with query on

```
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
```

Now you have the last added object from this node and you can simply get the key which will be PRO00013.
 1. Cast it to String
 2. Remove "PRO" from this string
 3. Cast the remaining to integer
 4. Add 1 to this integer
 5. Create new string variable and give it value "PRO" + the new integer
 6. Now push the object in ref.(the new string variable).setValue(object).
Now I don't know if you gonna implement this logic in a cloud function accepting some sort of params but if this is the case - this should work just fine.
**I also want to know WHY xD**